# fs.statSync throws an error when contained in a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exists, fs

I'm making a function that returns a boolean for when a file exists or not, using `fs.statSync`. It looks like this:

```
function doesExist (cb) {
  let exists
  try {
    fs.statSync('./cmds/' + firstInitial + '.json')
    exists = true
  } catch (err) {
    exists = err && err.code === 'ENOENT' ? false : true
  }
  cb(exists)
}
```

Example use case:

```
let fileExists
doesExist('somefile.json', function (exists) {
  fileExists = exists
})
```

However, running the code throws me a `TypeError: string is not a function`. I have no idea why.

Comment: Your `doesExist` function hasn't declared the `firstInitial` parameter in its parameter list: `function doesExist(firstInitial, cb) {`

Comment: WTH are you trying to use a callback when you are using a `*sync` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to remove that callback, and add the file name to your parameters:

```
function doesExist(firstInitial) {
  try {
    fs.statSync('./cmds/' + firstInitial + '.json')
    return true
  } catch(err) {
    return !(err && err.code === 'ENOENT');
  }
}

let fileExists = doesExist('somefile');
```

Btw, there is also [`fs.exists`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback).

Comment: but that's deprecated!

Comment: @kyr: Yeah, `fs.exists` is deprecated, but apparently only because people abused it (using it together with `fs.open`). I think if your use case is appropriate, you may still use it.